# CSS cloud animation issue

Tags: html, css, css-animations

the css animation (loop) ist not correct.
I made the example faster, so you can see it after every 5. second.
How can I fix that?

Demo:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/bt3vzwns/`
```

Comment: provide the markup/CSS rules .

Comment: Which one? I tried... (english is not my native language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `left: 100%`, it'll push left 100% of your div's width.

Since your cloud.png is 1000px wide, try `left: 1000px`; [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqye44gk/).

Comment: Thank you :) It works with chrome, but it seems not with FireFox.

Comment: Edit: And with Internet Explorer nothing work.. no animation.

Comment: Try with MS prefixes for the animation & -1000px everywhere : [exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/adsjtL8d/)

Comment: @Soya, you should also write a non-prefixed keyframe. If you don't use very specific parameters for your animation, latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and even IE should do fine without prefixes.

Comment: Glad to help ;)
Happy coding!